# Uncaught ReferenceError: boxChecked is not defined when it is?

Tags: javascript, function, debugging, typeerror

I keep getting the above error an uncaught type error saying something isn't a function when I think it is. I'll post the code and point out where I am referencing the elements. I'm making a Todo list which generates a todo item, a checkbox, and a remove icon. When users click the checkbox, I want it to apply the `text-decoration: line-through` to the Todo item. I added an `onclick="boxChecked"()` to the input with the checkbox and referenced right away in my function. It keeps saying in my HTML that it isn't defined. Is this because it is all JavaScript being referenced to the HTML doc externally? Maybe I have the function in the wrong spot?

Here is the Console Log
[image: Here is the Console Log]

```
function show() {
  var todos = get_todos();

  var html = "<ul>";
  for (var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
    html +=
      '<li class="todo-item">' +
      '<span class="todo-label">' +
      todos[i] +
      "</span>" +
      /*Here is the onclick--->*/ '<input onclick="boxChecked()" class="checkBox" type="checkbox">' +
      '<button class="remove" id="' +
      i +
      '">' +
      '<i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
      "</button>" +
      "</li>";
  }
  html += "</ul>";
  document.getElementById("todos").innerHTML = html;

  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("remove");
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", remove);
  }

  /*Here is the function for it---->*/ function boxChecked() {
    var x = document.getElementByClassName("todo-item");
    if (x.style.textDecoration === "none") {
      x.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    } else {
      x.style.textDecoration = "none";
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", add);
show();
```

Below is an image from **w3schools** where I tried it all on one page (without referencing it through an external JavaScript file) and it works. I'm really not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Your `boxChecked` function is inside your `show` function. Check your brackets.

Comment: Code in `onclick` attributes is executed in the global scope, you can't call local functions.